# MySQL fulltext search user input against keywords saved in DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, match-against

I am trying to select keywords from DB based on user-given text input. I tried both LIKE and MATCH AGAINST variants to compare which works better for me, but none of these works exactly as I need. I really prefer to use MATCH AGAINST because of better performance and determination of the relevance of the results.

The MATCH AGAINST fulfills my expectations except for one big problem. Let me show the problem on my concrete example:

```
SELECT * FROM skills WHERE MATCH(skillName) AGAINST('mam problem s javascriptovym frameworkem jquery.' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

In the table I have skills named "javascript" and "jquery". "jQuery" skill is selected by this query, but 
"JavaScript" isn't. Is there any way to select skills that match by the root of the word, not the whole word? I know how to solve the reverse situation (so in the table is the whole word and in the user input there is just a root of that word) - in that case, I just need to add * to the word in the user input. But I would need to do something like adding * to the value of the column - I know it isn't allowed.

The only solution which I realized is to change the MODE to WITH QUERY EXPANSION and to another column save other forms of the word which I guess should work but it would be very hard for me to manage this.

If I use the LIKE variant it looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM skills WHERE 'mam problem s javascriptovym frameworkem jquery.' LIKE CONCAT('%', skillName, '%')
```

This does exactly what I need to accomplish with MATCH AGAINST. I would use this but I am afraid of performance issues when the user input is very long and I don't know how to effectively work with relevance here...

Please, tell me you have some better solution than these I have written.
Thank you so much.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Can you post structure DB ?

Comment: Sure, I added it to my question.

Comment: So you need to select all value from skills where in skillName exist a word of that pharse ? (mam problem s javascriptovym frameworkem jquery)

Comment: You are right. This in fact works, if the match is exact ("jquery" in the phrase causes that the query returns "jquery" skill from the DB - good, but the problem is when in the phrase is "JAVASCRIPTovym" instead of an exact match ("javascript").

Comment: You need to implode pharse for result word like javascript - jquery ecc then use that in the query

Comment: But to do this I would need to know which keywords I am looking for, right? Or I would need to do this for each record from the database. This doesn't sound like an effective solution :-(